# How to determine where a drag event began relative to an object

Tags: jquery, drag, crop

I have a 100 x 100 px graphic of an upper right and lower left corner that I overlay an image with. These represent crop marks. I have a drag event bound to each that lets me drag these crop marks and then resize the image. It all works but no matter where I click on the corner image the mouse jumps to just left of the top left of the graphic. Since the graphic is 100 x 100 px I might have clicked on the lower right. I want the mouse (or finger) to stay at the same spot originally clicked (or touched) and not jump to off the upper left. Looking at the various offsets returned by the event (or this.offsetLeft, this.offsetTop) none of them seem to  give me the x,y offset from where the pointer ends up to where it began.

Is there a way to determine the starting point and keep that the point of contact for dragging?

Here is my drag handler for the upper right corner/crop:

```
function ur_crop()
{
    $('#ur_corner').bind('drag', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    curX = event.pageX; 
    curY = event.pageY; 
    offsetX = curX - ur_curX;
    offsetY = curY - ur_curY;
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).css({
        left: curX + 'px', 
        top: curY + 'px' 
    });

    ur_curX = curX; // + offsetX;
    ur_curY = curY; // + offsetY;

});
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tie jQuery's mousemove event in there after the corner drag is selected to get the position of the mouse.

### [Check out jQuery's documentation for mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't yield any additional information. The pageX and pageY returned by the mousemove event are identical to the pageX and pageY returned by the drag event. If I use those coordinates to move to the mouse cursor jumps immediately about an inch to the upper right of the crop mark. Currently I subtract 50 px from pageX and 100 px from pageY and that at least gets the cursor to the upper left of the crop mark but I still have not found a way to determine exactly where the mouse pointer (or finger) was on the crop mark when the mousedown or touch occurred.